# Как поставить изменить положение метки на карте при клике на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Есть яндекс-карта которая создается при загрузке страницы.
Задача при клике на элемент изменить координаты метки, если она есть. А если метки нет, то поставить ее туда.

так же не понял как сделать кнопку при клике на которую карта очищалась бы от меток.

А при клике на карту, ставилась бы новая метка, при суловии, что другие метки на ней не стоят.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
$('button').click(function() {
  var center = $(this).val().split(',');
  build(center[0], center[1], true);
});

function init() {
  var center = $('.default').val().split(',');

  console.log(center);
  build(center[0], center[1], true);
}

function build(x, y, point = false) {
  var myPlacemark,
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('mymap', {
      center: [x, y],
      zoom: 16
    });
  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([x, y], {}, {
    draggable: true
  });
  if (point) myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

  myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function() {
    console.log(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
  });
}
```

```css
#mymap {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<input class="default" type="hidden" value="  51.75521219508113,55.092615693602454">
<button class="test" name="test" value="53.893307,54.919211">53.893307, 54.919211</button>
<button class="test" name="test" value="50.893307,50.919211">50.893307, 50.919211</button>
<div id="mymap"></div>
```

**дополнил**

на этой странице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

показывается как по клику добавить точку на карту.

1. получаем ее координаты
2. передаем координаты в функцию `createPlacemark`

удалил клик, чтобы проверить сработает ли просто при загрузке документа. Но ничего не происходит почему? функция тпросто вызываю я ее напрямую без клика.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myPlacemark,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });
            myPlacemark = createPlacemark('55.84527343200916, 37.409232892578125');
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            getAddress('55.84527343200916, 37.409232892578125');



    // Создание метки.
    function createPlacemark(coords) {
        return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            iconCaption: 'поиск...'
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
            draggable: true
        });
    }

    // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
    function getAddress(coords) {
        myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
        ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

            myPlacemark.properties
                .set({
                    // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                    iconCaption: [
                        // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                        firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                        // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                        firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                    ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                    // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                    balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "Задача при клике на элемент изменить координаты метки, если она есть." На какой элемент?

Comment: в коде вставлены кнопки, как замена моим элементам))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Задача при клике на элемент изменить координаты метки, если она есть. 
>   А если метки нет, то поставить ее туда.

Как создать метку если её нет и изменить координаты метки если она есть можно посмотреть тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

> так же не понял как сделать кнопку при клике на которую карта очищалась бы от меток.

Для того чтобы удалить всё с карты можно воспользоваться методом removeAll() https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.GeoObjects-docpage/#method_detail__removeAll

> А при клике на карту, ставилась бы новая метка, при суловии, что другие метки на ней не стоят.

Проверить количество объектов на карте можно с помощью getLength() https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.GeoObjects-docpage/#method_detail__getLength

Всё меняется если на карте есть объекты кроме меток, которые удалять не нужно, тогда нужно воспользоваться коллекцией. Добавлять метки в коллекцию, проверять количество элементов в коллекции и удалять оттуда же. Вот пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geo_object_collection

Comment: воспользовался ссылкой которую вы указали в ответе. дополнил вопрос. Прочитав пример, стало понятно как обрабатываются события клика по карте, через это же событие вызывалась функция создания метки. Попробовал вызывать эту функцию напрямую при загрузке документа

Comment: Координаты в яндекс апи карт всегда передаются массивом чисел myPlacemark = createPlacemark([55.84527343200916, 37.409232892578125]); https://jsfiddle.net/8gdfv71w/

Comment: Надо понимать, что если вы будете получать адрес метки при каждом создании карты, то лимит на количество запросов очень быстро закончится. В бесплатной версии API суммарное число запросов не должно превышать 25 000 в сутки. В коммерческой версии этот лимит устанавливается тарифом. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/